# redis architecture for multiple groups of information

Tags: database, nosql, redis

Setup:  Imagine an application that stores 3 types of data in redis: 
1. session information
2. user status (online/offline)
3. user 3 favorite colors

I would like to ask about the right architecture to set this up.  Should I:
a. Merely store everything with different keys?  ie: 
a1) Store each session with: key = "session id", value = "session information", 
a2) Store each status with: key = "user id",  value = "online || offline", 
a3) Store each favorite color with: key = "user color1 || user color2 || user color3", value = "color name"
b. Store sessions with different keys, and use sets for status/favorite color? ie:
b1) Store each session with: key = "session id", value = "session information", 
b2) Create 2 sets online & offline: each online user in 'set online', each offline user in 'set offline'
b3) Create a 'color set' for each user:  In each set, store the 3 favorite colors.


c. Store sessions with different keys, and use lists for status/favorite color?
c1) Store each session with: key = "session id", value = "session information", 
c2) Create 2 lists online & offline: each online user in 'list online', each offline user in 'list offline'
c3) Create a 'color list' for each user:  In each list, store the 3 favorite colors.

d. Other option?

I'm concerned mostly with performance.  I want to perform queries on sessions, status, colors so as to make as efficient as possible (assume 5million + users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do strings for sessions. They're simple and you can set them to expire ([`SETEX`](http://redis.io/commands/setex)).

As for colors your going to incur a memory overhead for a set, so I would just store all three colors as 1 string value, serialized with either [JSON](http://www.json.org/) or [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) (ex. `SET colors:<user_id> '["red", "blue", "green"]'`).

For user status, its implied that if a user is not online, they're offline so I would waist time and space keeping two sets, just store which users are online. From my experience redis is more then fast enough to handle this as a set but another option would to use [redis bitmaps](http://redis.io/commands/setbit) to handle this data. See the blog post [Chandra Patni](http://blog.getspool.com/2011/11/29/fast-easy-realtime-metrics-using-redis-bitmaps/) for the details.